# How to read data efficiently from sanity's useSanityQuery

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, sanity

I am building an e-commerce site using sanity from product data storage(CMS) with [NuxtJS 3](https://nuxt.org) as the web framework. To fetch data I am using the useSanityQuery hook provided by the `@sanity/nuxt` package. It seems to return the data in this format.

```json
{
    _rawValue {
        productName: "XYZ",
        price: 111,
        etc
    }
    _value {
        productName: "XYZ",
        price: 111,
        etc
    }
}
```

Both the `_rawValue` and `_value` return very similar to the same content from my perspective. So I will be using `_rawValue` for this example.

For the products page, I send a query to sanity throght the `useSanityQuery` hook like so:

```js
import * as product from '../types/product'
const query = groq`*[_type=="product"]`
const { data: products }: { data: product.Iproduct[] } = await useSanityQuery(query)
```

The product types look like this:

```js
interface Iproduct {
    name: string,
    image: Iimage,
    slug: Islug,
    price: number,
    category: Icategory,
    description: string
}

interface Iimage {
    asset: Iasset
}

interface Iasset {
    _ref: string,
    _type: string
}
interface Icategory {
    _ref: string,
    _type: string
}

interface Islug {
    _type: string;
    current: string
}

export {
    Iproduct,
    Iimage,
    Iasset,
    Icategory,
    Islug
}
```

To display a card for each product, I loop over it with vue's `v-for` like so:

```js
<div class="grid grid-rows-6 p-0 m-0" v-for="product in products">
        <div class="card">
            <NuxtLink class="truncate" :to="product.slug.current"><p>{{ product.name }}</p></NuxtLink>
            <p>₹{{ product.price }}</p>
            <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

This gives a card for each product(seems to loop over fine from the `_rawValue`/`_value`) but when going to the actual product page how should I display the product when with typesafety as then I actually have to get the values of the product from the `_value`. Another thing is that if I take the value of `data` as `any` on

```js
let { data: product }: {data: any} = await useSanityQuery(query)
```

and then try to get its value like

```js
<p class="text-xl leading-5">{{ product.value[0].name }}</p>
```

This gives an error `500 cannot read the properties of undefined(reading [0])`

How should I go about solving both of these problems?